# Broken FileVault Drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, filevault, unlock

I'm coming to you having a few issues with my old hard drive.

Basically, my MacBook crashed a few days ago. It seems like my disk has some bad sectors and has started a kind of autodestruction process.

The issue I have is that his drive is locked with FileVault…
I have the master and recovery keys, however, no way to unlock the drive now I've extracted it from my computer.

I managed to unlock my volume and see my locked partition booting in recovery mode from this hard drive, but now I'm running on a new (and clear) HDD, I can't even list the CS groups (the old disk if plugged in USB):

```
# diskutil cs list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
```

When I run `diskutil info`:

```
# diskutil info /dev/disk2
   Device Identifier:        disk2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2
   Part of Whole:            disk2
   Device / Media Name:      APPLE HD D HTS547550A9E38 Media


   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)


   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)


   File System:              None


   Content (IOContent):      FDisk_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported


   Total Size:               500.1 GB (500107862016 Bytes) (exactly 976773168 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        4096 Bytes


   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
   Ejectable:                Yes


   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

Comment: Are you running the same operating system version that you were previously running? It's possible that an older OS may not be able to unlock the drive (even if it supports encryption [i.e., 10.7])? What does the system report when you attempt to run the Terminal command "diskutil cs info /dev/disk2"?